# How to add special characters in MSI installation argument?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, special-characters

Here i trying to install MSI package with argument in powershell where i have to pass few special characters as below:

```
$msi="/I mypkg.msi TARGETAPPPOOL='.NET v4.5 Classic' /L mai.log /qn"

Start-process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $msi -wait -nonewwindow -PassThru
```

Showing "1639" error code - A command line option passed to the installer is invalid.

Installation working well with default value, if I remove "TARGETAPPPOOL='.NET v4.5 Classic'”

Can you please suggest how we can write it?

Thanks

Comment: Try `TARGETAPPPOOL="".NET v4.5 Classic""`

Comment: @Theo tried this one as well, that also showing Syntex error. I tried single quote and double quote and applied diffrent combination but getting same issu

Comment: @zett42 thank this is work for me. Please put it on the answer, other people can take reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the arguments as an array like this:

```sh
$msi = '/I', 'mypkg.msi', 'TARGETAPPPOOL=".NET v4.5 Classic"', '/L', 'mai.log', '/qn'

Start-process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $msi -wait -nonewwindow -PassThru
```

PowerShell automatically adds space separator between the arguments.